# Postgres - how can you execute a multiline query from Python using psql on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, postgresql

I'd like to be able to run multiline queries with `psql`, and was trying to write a library function to do so, but I get a "Permission denied" error -

```
import os
import tempfile

sql = 'select 1;'
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w') as f:
    f.write(sql)
    cmd = f'psql --file "{f.name}"'
    os.system(cmd) # error: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as nice looking, but it works:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False)
f.write(sql)
f.close()
cmd = f'psql --file "{f.name}"'
os.system(cmd)
os.remove(f.name)
```

The error seems to be due to Windows not being able to open a file a second time -

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile